# I need help closing system processes using C++ in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, bsod

I've been experimenting with C++ lately, but something I can't get my head wrapped around is how to end the csrss.exe process with a C++ script. I was originally searching for ways to cause a BSOD and found on a [forum post](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/134975-blue-screen-of-death-code-c/?mode=linear) that killing csrss.exe is an easy solution. However, all of the tutorials and guides online are for eliminating normal-level processes and not system-level ones. Could you help me figure this out?

Comment: The OS does not allow you to do that under normal circumstances.

Comment: why do you want to kill that particular process in the first place?

Comment: in 2006 this was a solution. in win10 csrss.exe is protected process. anyway - what sense make BSOD ?

Comment: Just write your own Windows Driver and you can crash the system at will.

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't have enough experience to do that. Do you have any badly written hardware drivers?

Comment: @Raildex I said it in the post, i want to cause a BSOD (Blue Screen Of Death)

Comment: @IMSOASIAN just use one of sample drivers provided with the MS DDK

Comment: @RichardCritten To run? Or to create a driver? If it's the latter then I don't know how to do that unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Call RtlSetProcessIsCritical using LoadLibrary and GetProcAdress. After that call exit(0).